# fit parent div to select tag width

Tags: html, css, select

I need the `div container` fits with the width of the `select`

```
<div class="select_container">
    <select>
        <option>m</option>
        <option>n</option>
        <option>o</option>
        <option>p</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

When I set `.select_container{width:auto;}` it fits the width of the main table where is contained.

Comment: Maybe `display: inline-block;`, see [working here](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/mzbzfjsL/).

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
.select_container {
    display: inline;
}
```